# Liquibase loadData as string, not CLOB resource

Tags: migration, liquibase

### The Problem

I recently upgraded Liquibase to `3.6.2` from `3.4.2`.

Loading seed data from a CSV into text fields now results in a CLOB resource error.  Before it would simply insert the text as a value.

### The Setup

I'm using Liquibase to manage migrations of my data.

I have a table with an `code` and `description` column.  `description` is of type `TEXT`.

```xml
<changeSet author="" id="create-table-degrees">
  <createTable tableName="degrees">
    <column name="code"
            type="varchar(2)">
      <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="description"
            type="text">
      <constraints unique="true"/>
    </column>
  </createTable>
  <rollback>
    <dropTable tableName="degrees"/>
  </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

I have seed data in a CSV:

```xml
code,description
"D1","MASTERS"
"D2","DOCTORATE"
```

I load it using `loadData`:

```xml
<changeSet author="" id="seed-degrees">
  <loadData file="seeds/degrees.csv"
            tableName="degrees" />
</changeSet>
```

### The Error

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: CLOB resource not found: MASTERS

### The Question

Is there a way to keep Liquibase from interpreting seed values as file paths instead of strings, or do I need to manually define the column types as `String` in loadData.

e.g. I would like to avoid having to modify the old changeSet to:

```xml
<changeSet author="" id="seed-degrees">
  <loadData file="seeds/degrees.csv"
            tableName="roles">
    <column name="description" type="string" />
  </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Just a note that I have added an issue for this in the liquibase JIRA -- https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3287

Answer (score 6):

> The workaround listed in CORE-3287: Anver S December 3, 2018, 3:07 PM
>
> While adding an explicit column type definition as defined in original
>   stackoverflow post
>
> ```
> <column name="description" type="string" />
> ```
>
> does the trick - for me it effectively requires to update already
>   applied changesets which ideally I'd try to avoid.

Comment: Thank you for adding that directly -- though I won't mark it as an answer since that solution is actually part of the question (listed as something I want to avoid)

Answer (score 0):

try column name="description" type="varchar(1500)" for example to allow for longer text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change description column from text type to varchar (no need to give any limit in brackets).  It works the same and it loads without giving any column in loadData

```
<column name="description" type="varchar">
      <constraints unique="true"/>
</column>
```